# Return all object properties (including private) using reflection

Tags: c#

I looked up this here on stackoverflow as well as other sites including MS documents, and tried all possible answers I came across but to no avail.  Not sure, what I am doing wrong.  Simple class, trying to get all properties including the private one.

The solution is a console app in vs2017 15.5.7, c# 2017, netFramework 4.7.02

Tried all the binding flags combinations:

```
 (BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static)
 (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static |
 BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Including the code:

```
var listnew = new List<Test>
{
    new Test {Name = "Test"}
};

foreach (var item in listnew)
{
    var test = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (var prop in test)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(prop);
        System.Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(item));
    }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class Test
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    { 
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with `BindingFlags`?  It's hard to help you when we can't see what you tried.

Comment: You need to [edit] to show us *what you have tried* (that means code) and *why it didn't work for you*. That's an important part of asking a question that can get a quick and correct answer.

Comment: I don't see no code where you are using Reflection. No idea what you are doing and what you do wrong in particular. How can anybody tell you what you are doing wrong if nobody knows/sees what you are doing?

Comment: Also, your Test class does not have a private property, only a public one.

Comment: You should show a [mcve]. Trying to hide parts of your code that you think "is not related to the problem" doesn't help, instead try to **remove** those parts, and keep a minimal **complete** example.

Comment: Saw your edit. Your reflection code looks fine at first glance. As i already commented, your Test class has only a public property. Why would you think your Test class has private properties?

Comment: I guess you want properties _and_ fields, `GetProperties` doesn't return the private backing field but `GetFields` does.

Comment: @elgonzo apologies, not a private property but a backing field.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I see, so need to do GetFields as well.

Comment: Yupp, nomen est omen... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want properties *and* fields, `GetProperties` doesn't return the private backing field `_name` but `GetFields` does. You could concat fields and properties, both are `MemberInfo`:

```
Type t = typeof(Test);
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;

MemberInfo[] allMembers = t.GetProperties(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
    .Concat(t.GetFields(bindingFlags))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Could this also be done with `GetMembers(bindingFlags).OfType<MemberInfo>()`?

Comment: Thanks Tim, that'll do it.

Comment: @Amy: then you'll get not only members of this class but also inherited and also not only properties and fields but other member types. In this littlte class you will already get these: `System.String get_Name(); Void set_Name(System.String); Void Finalize(); System.Object MemberwiseClone(); 
 System.String Name; System.String _name`

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of metadata you care about: `FieldInfo` describing fields and `PropertyInfo` describing properties.
Here is a method which will print the full metadata for a given instance:

```
private static void PrintMetadata(Test item)
{
    Type type = item.GetType();

    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name + " :: " + field.GetValue(item));
    }

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " :: " + property.GetValue(item));
    }
}
```

Just call it from the loop for each item as follows:

```
var listnew = new List<Test>
{
    new Test {Name = "Test1"}
};

foreach (var item in listnew)
{

    PrintMetadata(item);
}
```

Hope this helps.